# How to hide/show sections of a HTML form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, show-hide

I have a HTML form which when submitted sends an email with all the questions and answers using PHP.

I need to break the form down as it's too long. I need only one submit button and for the form to load only once. This obviously means that I need to use JavaScript show/hides.

I've tried using many different types but I can't get them to work properly with my form. It is quite large and seems to be very complicated to get to work with show/hide :(

I've used show/hide divs before but not tables.

Anyone have anything that can help?

What I'd like is,

- A next button that takes you to another section of the form.
- Whilst on the next section you can return back to the previous section or go on to another section again.
- The last section to contain previous or submit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a table layout for your form?

Comment: What's more complicated with a table layout vs. sans table in terms of show/hide javascript?  Should be about the same.  Can you clarify what you've tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's quite a common request. Here is one way

- Break your form in pages using `div`s with easy to manage `id`s and only the first one visible

.

```
<form action=".." ..>
<!-- the first page has style set to be visible -->
<div id="formpage_1" style="visibility: visible; display: block; .."> 
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- NEXT button -->
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(1,2);">
</div>
<!-- the 2nd and following pages have style set to be invisible -->
<div id="formpage_2"  style="visibility: hidden; display: none; ..">
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons -->
  <input type="button" value="back" onclick="pagechange(2,1);">
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(2,3);">
</div>
...
<div id="formpage_10"  style="visibility: hidden; display: none; ..">
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- PREVIOUS and SUBMIT buttons -->
  <input type="button" value="back" onclick="pagechange(10,9);">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

- Use a simple JS function to switch between the pages

.

```
function pagechange(frompage, topage) {
  var page=document.getElementById('formpage_'+frompage);
  if (!page) return false;
  page.style.visibility='hidden';
  page.style.display='none';

  page=document.getElementById('formpage_'+topage);
  if (!page) return false;
  page.style.display='block';
  page.style.visibility='visible';

  return true;
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to use a table layout, break the for into more tables (one for each page) and give the `id`s to the tables instead of the `div`s

Comment: There was a typo in the JS function - used `frompage` twice instead of `topage`in the second use - fixed.

Comment: This works perfectly when using divs. If I use tables the back and next buttons appear from all tables and none of them show/hide. They also all appear at the top and wont move down.

Any idea? Don't really want to use divs as I'll need to re-style everything.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you wrote `<table id="formpage_1">` ?

Comment: <table id="formpage_1" style="visiblity: visible; display:block;" class="widthOneHundredPercent"> .... Just spoke to my boss and he suggests putting the table within the div. That way we wont have to re-style everything, think that might be the way to go.

Comment: Also @Eugen when I click next on a form that is very long it takes me half way down the next form as opposed to the top of it. any way to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to organize the form in the view, how about something like a accordion widget? Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're happy to use CSS only (and bear in mind the cross-browser issues that may arise), one approach is to use the `:target` pseudo-class.

Separate the form into related groups of inputs, using in this case the `fieldset` tag. Give each fieldset an `id` attribute and target those `fieldset`s using `a` tags.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <a href="#one">Page One</a>
    <fieldset id="one">
        <legend>Page One</legend>
        <label for="p1i1">label for input one</label>
        <input id="p1i1" />
        <label for="p1i2">label for input two</label>
        <input id="p1i2" />
    </fieldset>

    <a href="#two">Page Two</a>
    <fieldset id="two">
        <legend>Page Two</legend>
        <label for="p2i1">label for input three</label>
        <input id="p2i1" />
        <label for="p2i2">label for input four</label>
        <input id="p2i2" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    height: 0;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
fieldset:target {
    display: block;
    height: 5em;
    -o-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FnnNY/1/).

References:

- [`:target` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo).